# Interior, exterior and boundary points of a set

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I recently got this question as part of a complex analysis course but no answer was ever offered:

Does $S = \{z_1,...,z_k\}$ have any interior points? What are the exterior points of $S$? What is the boundary of $S$?

I feel like $S$ does not have any interior points (the $\varepsilon$-neighbourhood that contains a point would have to have $\varepsilon=0$ for it to not contain any other points), that the boundary points are $S$ and that the exterior points are $S^C$, but I'm not sure that I'm right and I'm having a hard time writing an answer that says this in any rigorous way.

Any hints/properly structured answers are very welcome. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is right. Every $ε$-neigborhood of a point $z_i$ in $ℂ$ is infinite, and so cannot be contained in the finite set $S$. Also, $S$ is closed since it is finite. It follows that exterior points are $ℂ \setminus S$ and closure points are $S$, so boundary points are also $S$ since the interior is empty.

The same holds for any finite subset of a $T_1$ topological space without isolated points.